# How to root my moto g 4g xt1039?

Tags: rooting, stock-android, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

I own a Motorola moto g 4g and I want to root it. Is there a simple way to do that? It's running on android 5.1

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to unlock the bootloader by visiting here:
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a
Then you will need to flash a supersu.zip. Can search for that on Xda.
Also you will need a few additionals like fastboot and adb tools.